# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template for a js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem running one of my tests for a controller. The error that I am getting is a missing template:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate Missing template vulnerabilities/vulnerabilities_per_version, application/vulnerabilities_per_version 
with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}
```

Here is my `routes.rb` file:

```
......code....
get 'security' => 'vulnerabilities#vulnerabilities_per_version', as: :vulnerabilities, defaults: { format: 'js' }
......code.....
```

As you can see, I am clearly crafting the format to accept js only and the call is indeed coming through as `JS` on the logs.

Here is the controller:

```
class VulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  def vulnerabilities_per_version
    @release_versions = @releases.map(&:version).to_json
  end
end
```

And here is my view:

```
app/views/vulnerabilities/vulnerabilities_per_version.js.erb

$(function () {
 $('#vulnerabilities').highcharts({
     chart: {
         type: 'column',
         events: {
         load: function() {
             this.renderer.image('http://i64.tinypic.com/25irqt5.png', 60, 30, 280, 30)
                 .add();
             }
         }
     },
     credits: {
         enabled: false
     },
     title: {

     ....code....
```

Here is my controller test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class VulnerabilitiesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  it 'should retrieve the 10 most recent releases for a project' do
    @project = create(:project)
    @project.project_security_sets << create(:project_security_set)
    @project.project_security_sets[0].releases << create_list(:release, 10)
    @project.project_security_sets[0].releases.each do |r|
      r.vulnerabilities << create(:vulnerability)
    end
    @project.update!(best_project_security_set_id: @project.project_security_sets[0].id, editor_account: create(:admin))
    get :vulnerabilities_per_version, id: @project.id, xhr: true
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal 10, @project.best_project_security_set.releases.count
    assert_equal @project.best_project_security_set.releases.order(released_on: :asc), assigns(:releases)
  end
end
```

It's been awhile since I've worked with rendering a javascript file but I should have the necessary components in place.

I have the request coming in as js, the response is accepted and I can see my highchart render from the `js.erb` file. I've tried a `respond_to` block but that didn't seem to get me anywhere as the error changed from `200` to `404`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the request format in your controller test:

`get :vulnerabilities_per_version, id: @project.id, xhr: true, format: :js`

Answer (score 1):

You definitely must specify to the controller that it must respond through the `js.erb` file.
As you can see in your error message, Rails is looking for a HTML template and doesn't find one (he's looking for vulnerabilities_per_version.html.erb).

So, in your `vulnerabilities_per_version` method in your controller, just after the `@release_versions = @releases.map(&:version).to_json` line, add:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js  # <-- will render `app/views/vulnerabilities/vulnerabilities_per_version.js.erb`
end
```

Let me know if it works out.
All the best.